# How to to burst array by timestamp dict attribute and sort by timestamp

Tags: python

I want burst array with same `["content"]["system.id"]` or `["content"]["target.uid"]`. With `typeB`, this object contain a list of timestamp (key) or with `typeA`, this object contain "date" attribute.

We need keep order of timestamp (`typeB`) and date (`typeA`).

in a sample, `["content"]["system.id"]` or `["content"]["target.uid"]` = 123456789

and the list of timestamp in order is 1693217400000, 1693217450000, 1693217460000, 1693217500000 and 1693217550000

Init of my code is:

```
products = ...
tmp = {}
for item in products :
    if item["name"] == "typeB":
        tmp.setdefault(p["content"]["system.id"], []).append(p)
    elif item["name"] == "typeA":
        tmp.setdefault(p["content"]["target.uid"], []).append(p)

out = []
for k, v in tmp.items():
    for e in v:
        for t in e["content"].items():
            out.append(v[0])
```

My input is:

```
products = [
    {
        "name": "typeA",
        "date": 1693217460000,
        "content": {
            "rule.uid": "id",
            "target.uid": "123456789",
            "state": None,
            "attributes": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217450000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "1"},
            "1693217550000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
]
```

and I need this output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"}
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217450000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "1"}
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeA",
        "date": 1693217460000,
        "content": {
            "rule.uid": "id",
            "target.uid": "123456789",
            "state": None,
            "attributes": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217550000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"}
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    }
]
```

Comment: Add the original data to the question, please.

Comment: @СергейКох, is it `products` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas to transform your data. You will need your own function and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode) to get one row per timestamp:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(products)

def dict_to_lists(d):
    if 'rule.uid' in d:
        return [d]
    l = []
    id_dict = {k: v for k,v in d.items() if 'id' in k}
    for t, v in d.items():
        if 'id' not in t:
            r = id_dict.copy()
            r.update({t: v})
            l.append(r)
    return l

df['content'] = df['content'].apply(dict_to_lists)
df = df.explode('content')
```

`df` will at this point look like this:

```
    name           date                                                                                                               content
0  typeA  1693217460000                                        {'rule.uid': 'id', 'target.uid': '123456789', 'state': None, 'attributes': ''}
1  typeB  1693217443241  {'system.id': '123456789', 'communication.id': '99', 'message.id': 'b0fa2', '1693217400000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'}}
1  typeB  1693217443241  {'system.id': '123456789', 'communication.id': '99', 'message.id': 'b0fa2', '1693217500000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'}}
2  typeB  1693217443241  {'system.id': '000000001', 'communication.id': '99', 'message.id': 'b0fa2', '1693217400000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'}}
2  typeB  1693217443241  {'system.id': '000000001', 'communication.id': '99', 'message.id': 'b0fa2', '1693217500000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'}}
3  typeB  1693217443241  {'system.id': '123456789', 'communication.id': '99', 'message.id': 'b0fa2', '1693217450000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '1'}}
3  typeB  1693217443241  {'system.id': '123456789', 'communication.id': '99', 'message.id': 'b0fa2', '1693217550000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'}}
```

You can then use a key made of (id, timestamp) to sort your df:

```
def sorting_val(row):
    if 'rule.uid' in row['content']:
        return (-int(row['content']['target.uid']), row['date'])
    for k in row['content'].keys():
        if 'id' not in k:
            return (-int(row['content']['system.id']), int(k))

df['sorting_val'] = df.apply(sorting_val, axis=1)
```

Sort your df and export it to a dictionary:

```
output = (df.sort_values('sorting_val')
            .drop(columns='sorting_val')
            .to_dict(orient='records'))
```

`output`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217450000": {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeA",
        "date": 1693217460000,
        "content": {
            "rule.uid": "id",
            "target.uid": "123456789",
            "state": null,
            "attributes": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217500000": {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217550000": {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217500000": {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "0"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
import copy

products = [
    {
        "name": "typeA",
        "date": 1693217460000,
        "content": {
            "rule.uid": "id",
            "target.uid": "123456789",
            "state": None,
            "attributes": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "typeB",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217450000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "1"},
            "1693217550000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
]

tmp = {}
for p in products:
    if p["name"] == "typeB":
        tmp.setdefault(p["content"]["system.id"], []).append(p)
    elif p["name"] == "typeA":
        tmp.setdefault(p["content"]["target.uid"], []).append(p)
        
out = {}
for k, v in tmp.items():
    for obj in v:
        if obj["name"] == "typeB":
            obj["content"] = dict(sorted(obj["content"].items(), key=None, reverse=True))
            for i in range(3,len(obj["content"])):
                copyobj = copy.copy(obj)
                copyobj["content"] = {}
                copyobj["content"]["system.id"] = obj["content"]["system.id"]
                copyobj["content"]["communication.id"] = obj["content"]["communication.id"]
                copyobj["content"]["message.id"] = obj["content"]["message.id"]
                key = list(obj["content"])[i]
                val = list(obj["content"].values())[i]
                copyobj["content"][key] = val
                copyobj["timestamp"] = key
                out.setdefault(obj["content"]["system.id"], []).append(copyobj)
        elif obj["name"] == "typeA":
            obj["timestamp"] = str(obj["date"])
            out.setdefault(obj["content"]["target.uid"], []).append(obj)

results = {}
for k, v in out.items():
    v2 = sorted(v, key=lambda d: d['timestamp'], reverse=False)
    for e in v2:
        del e["timestamp"]
    results[k] = v2
    
    
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(results)
```

**console:**

```
{   '000000001': [   {   'content': {   '1693217400000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'},
                                        'communication.id': '99',
                                        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
                                        'system.id': '000000001'},
                         'date': 1693217443241,
                         'name': 'typeB'},
                     {   'content': {   '1693217500000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'},
                                        'communication.id': '99',
                                        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
                                        'system.id': '000000001'},
                         'date': 1693217443241,
                         'name': 'typeB'}],
    '123456789': [   {   'content': {   '1693217400000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'},
                                        'communication.id': '99',
                                        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
                                        'system.id': '123456789'},
                         'date': 1693217443241,
                         'name': 'typeB'},
                     {   'content': {   '1693217450000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '1'},
                                        'communication.id': '99',
                                        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
                                        'system.id': '123456789'},
                         'date': 1693217443241,
                         'name': 'typeB'},
                     {   'content': {   'attributes': '',
                                        'rule.uid': 'id',
                                        'state': None,
                                        'target.uid': '123456789'},
                         'date': 1693217460000,
                         'name': 'typeA'},
                     {   'content': {   '1693217500000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'},
                                        'communication.id': '99',
                                        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
                                        'system.id': '123456789'},
                         'date': 1693217443241,
                         'name': 'typeB'},
                     {   'content': {   '1693217550000': {'c1': '0', 'c2': '0'},
                                        'communication.id': '99',
                                        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
                                        'system.id': '123456789'},
                         'date': 1693217443241,
                         'name': 'typeB'}]}
```